# Repeated "859: unexpected token" exceptions in a Rails 6 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bots

Over the last several weeks, my Rails 6.1 app has been raising hundreds of exceptions like the following:

```
An ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError occurred in regdevs#create:
859: unexpected token at 
'utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=fnrg63qtelQvkQx9NQx8SaZIp7mR500toEiWdaJe91
%2FOzsEvRbGD4Ow6NNADCtjw7H3EkDvFZVGP4gQkGZceEw%3D%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=jrmills91
%40hotmail.com&user%5Bfirst_name%5D=wJAhzNnPWbqMdfH&user%5Blast_name%5D=tKdp
IVXJlneZbiuA&user%5Bnickname%5D=lBdbyYgiaHt&user%5Bpassword%5D=0SgLpVuf5Wqs
%21&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=0SgLpVuf5Wqs%21&user%5Bterms_of_service
%5D=1&commit=Complete+registration&g-recaptcha-response=dzghTWcBpmI'
```

The error occurs when "someone" tries to register for a new account (via Devise) with bogus credentials. It clearly looks like some sort of attack.

I have two questions:

1. How can I find out more about this specific `859 unexpected token` error?
2. Should I be concerned? The recaptcha guard seems effective in blocking account creation, but I wonder if I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

I partially decoded the response by hand mostly just to see what it looked like.

```
utf8=%E2%9C%93
authenticity_token=fnrg63qtelQvkQx9NQx8SaZIp7mR500toEiWdaJe91/OzsEvRbGD4Ow6NNADCtjw7H3EkDvFZVGP4gQkGZceEw==
user[email]=jrmills91@hotmail.com
user[first_name]=wJAhzNnPWbqMdfH
user[last_name]=tKdpIVXJlneZbiuA
user[nickname]=lBdbyYgiaHt
user[password]=0SgLpVuf5Wqs!
user[password_confirmation]=0SgLpVuf5Wqs!
user[terms_of_service]=1
commit=Complete+registration
g-recaptcha-response=dzghTWcBpmI
```

The first line is `utf8=` and then that is the unicode for [checkmark](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9984&number=128).  Perhaps that is part of the captcha?

The user names etc clearly look bogus.  I bet jrmills is getting lots of weird email. :-)

The ParseError is defined in [parameters.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L19) and you can see the call that created it inside [parse_formatted_parameters](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L87).  The only place that calls it is from [request.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L402).

From the comments in the code (and what I would expect), if the authenticity_token doesn't match, an [ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.6.1/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) should be raised.  So, the parse error (I'm guessing) is lower down but I can't spot why the JSON or Ruby code would be complaining.  I think I would have written that piece of code differently: captured the error and included the original error message with the new error -- but... such is life.

I would attempt to track down the IP address where these are being sent from and block that IP address if possible or at least see if it is the same address or if they form a pattern.

Depending upon what you are protecting would alter my level of concern.  It seems plausible that a validation on the first and last name could be written that would reject this particular style of name.  i.e. capital letters in the middle of the name?  You could also flag any email going to "bogus" places like hotmail, yahoo, gmail, etc and require them to go through a moderator before being approved.

It also seems plausible to rig up a test case using this response to recreate the issue.  Then add debug code to the Rails code until the precise reason for the exception is better understood.